# I can't see my react version in git bash but I have the files and folders

Tags: reactjs, git-bash

This is my first time using react and I'm having a hard time using it. I tried following the tutorials on youtube and also read blogs on how to install react. But whenever I use git bash, it always ended up like this.

```
react --version    
bash: react: command not found
```

But I can see the files and folders. And I think it's related to how I can't use HTML tags on my return function. Whenever I tried typing HTML tags, it always ended up like this:

```
function App() {
    return ( <
        div >
        <
        h1 > Yo < /h1> < /
        div >
    );
}
```

The result was empty and I can't type tags inside of the return function. I tried uninstalling and installing it but it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

React Libray don't have bash or cmd commands.

Just Check your pagekage.json for `"version"`.